# do not show viewPager indicator for certain views

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-view, viewpagerindicator

My viewPager has 4 views and I am able to use `ViewPagerIndicator.setViewPager` to show indicator for those four views.
I am new to Android development and curious that are we able to use `ViewPagerIndicator` to only show indicator for the second and third views in my 4 views? That means that on the first and last view, there are no indicators on them. (I posted a picture below)

[image]

```
    vPager.setAdapter(vAdapter);

    indicator.setFillColor(.....);
    indicator.setPageColor(....);
    indicator.setStrokeColor(....);
    indicator.setRadius((int) (.....);
    indicator.setViewPager(vPager);
    indicator.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    indicator.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    indicator.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    break;
                default:
                    indicator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    indicator.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    indicator.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    break;
                default:
                    indicator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mFreViewPagerIndicator.setVisibility(mFreViewPager.INVISIBLE);

                    break;
            }

            vAdapter.getItem(position).onFragmentSelected();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        }
```

Comment: You could try to use `OnPageChangeListener()` and show/hide indicator programmatically with `Visibility` property depending on page that is shown?

Comment: @BlindKai Thanks for the direction. Let me try out.

Comment: Give me a moment to try few code lines, or provide your if it's possible.

Comment: @BlindKai I made some progress. I added this code in onPageSelected and onPageScrolled :                  switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        indicator.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        indicator.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        break;
                    default:
                        indicator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        break;
                }
But when I was on the page 2, 3, I saw four indicators instead of 2.

Comment: do you have an opportunity to edit the indicator? If yes, you probably want to do that. For example you could remove icons? Could you provide code with dependencies so I could check it? Don't want to post blind ideas.

Comment: how could I edit the indicator? I posted some code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197908/discussion-between-blind-kai-and-user3369592).